# Is enum to int unboxing?

Tags: c#, enums, boxing, unboxing

```
enum Season { spring, summer, fall, winter }
int a = (int)Season.spring;
```

Is this a unboxing or just a normal casting?
If this is a unboxing, could you explain why?
I thought this is just a normal casting because 'enum' and 'int' is both a value-type data.

Comment: What makes you think it is unboxing?

Comment: In fact, your code would just store the constant value 0 into a. The produced IL is `ldc.i4.0 stloc.0`

Comment: @KlausGütter That is assuming it doesn't skip the assignment altogether - https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs7o65gDsArgFs6AZRgBDAM4Q+bOlIAOUbHwDmaBcKEwomgGYTcuTQHdVGXXQC+PLlwt0JdALx0AFBYCU46bIB0SirqANx23JT2tAwodACy7l5s4baU1kA= (since 0 is default).

Comment: It's actually neither, at least in the IL. The enum *is* an integer, it doesn't need to be casted

Comment: Ultimately, for it to be unboxing: you'd first need a box. And that only happens when treating a value-type as `object`, `dynamic`, an interface type, or something like `Enum`; no, this is not unboxing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in [ECMA-334 11.3.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A1321%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C55%2C309%2C0%5D), C# defines a conversion to and from an `enum` type and its underlying type:

However, this does not specify whether or not it is an unboxing conversion. That could be deduced, though, from the fact that both the enum and the integer are value-types, therefore no unboxing is involved.

[ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A405%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C241%2C0%5D), which defines the CLR, makes it more clear that an `enum` is not just convertible to an integer, it actually *is* the integer, there is no conversion done at all:

> **14.3 Enums**
>
> For binding purposes (e.g., for locating a method definition from the method reference used to call it) enums shall be distinct from their underlying type.  **For all other purposes, including verification and execution of code, an unboxed enum freely interconverts with its underlying type.**  Enums can be boxed (§13) to a corresponding boxed instance type, but this type is not the same as the boxed type of the underlying type, so
> boxing does not lose the original type of the enum.